# $z=f(x,y)$ is differentiable on $R^2$, which of the following is correct?

Tags: calculus

1. If all the level curves of $f(x,y)$ are parallel lines, then $z=f(x,y)$ is a plane.
2. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ everywhere on $R^2$, then $z=f(x,y)$ is a plane.
3. If $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}=0$ everywhere on $R^2$, then $z=f(x,y)$ is a plane.

I think 1 is not correct, imagining a straight line moving parrellely in a twisted curve? 3 is obviously not correct for $z=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: 1 and 2, but not 3.

Comment: I think 1 is not correct. Imagine a half-cylinder which is perpendicular to the yz-plane ?

Comment: You're right, but that counterexample doesn't work, as it's not defined on all $\Bbb{R}^2$. If you have all these thoughts about the problem, then why not include them in the question? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. False; e.g. $f(x, y) = x^3$.
2. True. In fact, $f$ is constant. Suppose $f(\vec{x}) \neq f(\vec{y})$, and consider the function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(\lambda) = f(\lambda \vec{x} + (1 - \lambda)\vec{y}).$$ Since $f$ is differentiable, so too is $g$, and the derivative is given by
   $$g'(\lambda) = D_{\vec{u}}(\lambda \vec{x} + (1 - \lambda)\vec{y}) = \nabla f(\lambda \vec{x} + (1 - \lambda)\vec{y}) \cdot \vec{u},$$
   where $\vec{u} = \frac{\vec{x} - \vec{y}}{\|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\|}$. But, since $\nabla f \equiv (0, 0)$, this derivative is $0$. Therefore, $g$ is a non-constant function with constant $0$ derivative, contradicting the mean value theorem.
3. False, for the reason you stated.